# Laravel 5.5 redis queue is too slow

Tags: laravel-5, redis, queue

I have dispatch call in action:

```
dispatch(new ProcessVideo($video));
logger('After dispatch at ' . Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s.u'));
```

and job:

```
public function handle() : void
{
    logger('ProcessVideo@handle at ' . Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s.u'));
}
```

In logs we can see that interval between dispatch and handling from queue **more than 2.5 seconds**!

```
[2017-10-11 00:02:55] local.DEBUG: After dispatch at 00:02:55.423141  
[2017-10-11 00:02:58] local.DEBUG: ProcessVideo@handle at 00:02:58.071249
```

What the problem can be here? It's my local machine and it's only ONE job which was dispatched to test functionality

Comment: How is your Job being handled? Are you using a database queue or something similar?
Maybe add your .env file so we can get a better understanding of your situation.

Comment: @HansVn I use Redis queue

Comment: I've also noticed that the queue has quite a bit of latency, definitely not ideal for use with websockets.

Comment: Are you sure you have redis set in your .env file as being the queue driver? I was calling Redis in my code, but the queue driver in .env was set as "sync" and experienced the same slowness. Switching to Redis made it instant.

Comment: @stef yes, I'm sure. Do not you have any latencies?

Comment: With the `sync` driver I did but with Redis I can dispatch hundreds of jobs with almost no latency. At least nothing noticeable for my use case. This makes sense since it's basically like writing records to a database. Are you 100% sure you've set Redis properly as the driver? In the `queue.php` config I have `'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'redis'),` and in `.env`I have `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis`

Answer (score 3):

I face the similar issue as you. There's around 2-3 second delay when processing the first job.

After searching around, I found that laravel queue worker 
[default 3 second sleep](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Queue/WorkerOptions.html).

Which mean the first job will delay 3 second at worse case.

To solve it, just specify --sleep=0 when running the worker. Hope it helps.

```
php artisan queue:worker --sleep=0
```

Comment: It seems the worker won't go below 1 seconds though to `--sleep=0` is kind of deceptive. I suggest anyone who came here looking for some check this out: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13932