# Laravel 5.6 slow redis queue performance

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5.6

I have a small deployment projects which runs a bunch of Jobs which runs a bunch of Jobs in sequence through Job chaining:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#dispatching-jobs

From the get-go I have set up Redis to handle my queues but I quickly came to realise that using the `sync` driver is way easier for testing purposes.

When I switched the driver in my `.env` file and relaunched the Jobs ran way faster. They are communicating to my frontend through the `laravel-echo` server and pusher. I have listener set up to listen to the deployment start and the frontend receeives the data instantly.

With Redis this usually takes a couple of seconds before I even get the very first notification.

I have kept my configuration pretty close to the default and am using Homestead. Is there something I am not aware of that can possible increase my Redis performance or will the `sync` driver always be magnitudes faster?

If you need any more information please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The point is, `sync` driver uses the main thread for execution of tasks which is useful for only when you are in development.The main idea of queuing long running tasks is to be able to execute them in some background process so your main application thread won't block and you can serve your client requests more quickly.

Comment: I know the difference. This still does not explain the enormous performance difference though. The `sync` driver picks up Jobs instantly while the `redis` driver take a couple of seconds to even pick up on the first Job.

Comment: I did not test this but take a look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/51644983/8830631]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I will try this out later this evening and let you know.